# TTS voice is disabled

Tags: runtime-error, text-to-speech, voice

I have many Voices installed on my Windows OS system. I am trying to use these voices for Text To Speech (TTS). Many of them I cannot use and the following error message is displayed: "The selected voice is not installed or is disabled"

How can I 'Enable' these voices?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

One day this helped me

The Text-to-Speech tab in the Speech tool in Control Panel presents the options for each TTS engine. In addition to the general options, each engine can have a different set of specific features. For that reason, not all the resulting dialog boxes will look the same. It is possible that no special features have been included and some of the properties buttons will not have an associated dialog box.

Setting Up Your Hardware
NOTE:I assumes that you use Classic View in Control Panel. To change views, follow these steps:

```
Click Start, and then click Control Panel.
In Control Panel, click Switch to Classic View or Switch to Category View.
```

**Set Up Speakers**
Speakers vary greatly in design and purpose. Consult the speaker manual for hardware and software specifics. However, most models can be installed in a similar fashion.

**To set up speakers, follow these steps:**

```
Locate the sound connections and connect the speaker jack to the computer. Most computers use an internal sound card and often the connections are in the back of the computer. These are a series of connections the same size and diameter as the speaker jack. In many cases there are two sound out connections:
    One will be labeled as a line-out connection. Most speakers that require a separate power supply (such as an electrical (AC) adapter or batteries) should use this connection. It is also used to export amplified sound to recording devices including recordable CDs and tape cassette systems.
    The other connection is for the non-powered speakers. Because the signal is boosted by the computer, powered speakers may be damaged if connected. 
Plug the speaker into the proper connection.
To test the connection, follow these steps:
    Click Start, click Control Panel, and then double-click Speech.
    On the Text-to-Speech tab, click Preview Voice to hear the currently selected voice. The text is spoken and the words are highlighted as they are spoken. If the speakers are working properly, you will hear the spoken words. 
If you do not hear sound after you connect the speakers, see the "Possible Text-to-Speech Problems" section of this article for troubleshooting procedures.
```

**Select an Audio Output Device**
To select an audio output device, follow these steps:

```
Click Start, click Control Panel, and then double-click Speech.
On the Text-to-Speech tab, click Audio Output.
Select either Use preferred audio output device or Use this audio output device.
    Use preferred audio device sets the output device as the default for the system. Select this option if you want to use the same output device for speech as all other sound for the system. It is also the default option for Speech properties. Often, computers will have only one output device, such as a pair of speakers. The default device is designated in the appropriate sounds or multimedia properties in Control Panel for each operating system. Additional information for the specific panel is available through the associated Help files.
    Use this audio output device allows you to select another device for speech programs only. The drop-down list is active if other devices are available. In this drop-down list, select the device that you want. This does not change the default device for other audio programs. For example, you may want all speech output to go through your headset rather than the speakers.
```

**Set Audio Output Device Options**
By default, this option is disabled. However, other speech engines may include advanced properties for audio line out options. If so, Audio Output will be available. Follow instructions on the screen or those documented separately for the specific engine.

**To set up audio output device options, follow these steps:**

```
Click Start, click Control Panel, and then double-click Speech.
On the Text-to-Speech tab, click Audio Output.
Follow the instructions presented on the screen.
```

*Configure Text-to-Speech Options*
Determine the Selected TTS Voice or Engine
*To determine the selected Text-to-Speech voice, follow these steps:*

```
Click Start, click Control Panel, and then double-click Speech.

On the Text-to-Speech tab, the displayed name in the Voice selection drop-down list is the currently active voice.
Click Preview Voice to hear the active voice. The text is spoken and the words are highlighted as they are spoken.
```

*Preview TTS Voice*
To preview the Text-to-Speech voice, follow these steps:

```
Click Start, click Control Panel, and then double-click Speech.

On the Text-to-Speech tab, the displayed name in the Voice selection drop-down list is the active voice.
Click Preview Voice to hear the currently selected voice. The text is spoken and the words are highlighted as they are spoken.
During playback, Preview Voice will change to Stop. Click Stop to interrupt the voice playback.
```

*NOTE*:You can change the text to be read by the Preview Voice by highlighting the text and typing in new text. These changes are not permanent and when you reopen Speech properties or select a different voice, the text will reset to the default.

*Change the TTS Voice or Engine*
To change the Text-to-Speech voice or engine, follow these steps:

```
Click Start, click Control Panel, and then double-click Speech.
On the Text-to-Speech tab, the name displayed in the Voice selection drop-down list is the active voice.
Click the active voice inside the drop-down list, or use the arrow to display a list of available voices.
Click a new voice to select it.

The newly selected voice speaks the text in Preview Voice box.
Click OK or Apply to accept the new voice.
```

*Notes:*

```
A Text-to-Speech voice is closely associated with a particular speech engine. It may not be clear from the displayed name which language a voice is using. After selecting a speech engine or voice, test the voice and language by clicking Preview Voice.
The language or voices supported by a speech engine may not be obvious from the engine's displayed name. Refer to the specific user's guide for detailed information about the engine. This includes not only the language supported, but also the lexicon purpose. The lexicon purpose indicates whether it is a general grammar or jargon specific to a profession such as legal or medical.
Microsoft does not provide additional speech engines (voices), but a number of third-party products are available that support the new Microsoft Speech API. For information on these products, visit the following Microsoft Web site:
http://www.microsoft.com/speech/evaluation/thirdparty/engines.mspx
```

*Change TTS Voice Rate*
*To change the Text-to-Speech voice rate, follow these steps:*

```
Click Start, click Control Panel, and then double-click Speech.
Select the Text-to-Speech tab.
Move the Voice speed slider to change the rate of the Text-to-Speech voice. By default, it is set to Normal.
Click Preview Voice to hear the currently selected voice at the new rate. The text is spoken and the words are highlighted as they are spoken.
```

*To Change the Text-to-Speech Volume*
To adjust the volume output levels, follow the procedure below. Note that not all devices support this option in the same way. Some devices will not support volume control and the Volume button will be unavailable. Other devices may use their own display. In those cases, follow the instructions presented on the screen or documented separately with the engine.

```
Click Start, click Control Panel, and then double-click Speech.
On the Text-to-Speech tab, click Audio Output, and then click Volume.
A volume control mixer will be displayed. Adjust the appropriate device to the required level.
```

Refer 
 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306902
http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080125142917AAhJ1QB